# How to migrate from application.yml containing sensitive data of ansible vault to Kubernetes conf objects [Kubernetes/SpringBoot/Docker]

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to move SpringBoot application running in container to Kubernetes. All clear and no problems until I tried to figure out a way to move configuration files such as application.yml to objects.

The problem I have is that some sensitive data is currently managed by ansible vault. In application.yml I have variables ${SOME_SENSITIVE_DATA}, which I need to fill, so I can't just use entire application.yml as configMap.

I moved all sensitive data variables to Secret object, but now I don't know how to use those secrets in combination with application.yml. If application.yml could be moved in it's entirety into configMap that would be fine, but it can't. Searching the internet, I found migration examples without the need of doing that.

If I would not need to change code and rebuild image would be great. I have tried searching the internet for an answer but all I got is that I should change application code.

Comment: You can [set individual Spring properties from environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables), and [set environment variables from Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables); you don't need to inject the entire `application.yml`.  Will a setup like that help?

Comment: If you have a secret, spring-cloud-kubernetes can treat those as a property source.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/reference/property-source-config/secrets-propertysource.html